# Get reason for connection refused?

Tags: networking, ssh

I am using a code deployment service that connects to my server and execute commands. It connects, run some commands, disconnects and repeat.

I am always getting connection refused on the 8th connection within the same deployment.

From the service itself, all I can see is `ssh: connect to host xxx port 22: Connection refused`

I only see the connecting and disconnecting in `/var/log/auth.log` -- No connection refused errors.

For reference this is what I see in `auth.log`:

```
Accepted publickey for envoyer from 159.203.66.107 port 50177 ssh2: RSA
...
Received disconnect from 159.203.66.107 port 50177:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from 159.203.66.107 port 50177
pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user envoyer
Removed session 5996.
... repeated
```

How can I find out why it's refusing connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's nice to know what system you are trying to connect.Make sure that your script close session correctly. Some systems keep session  in case if terminated incorrect. As result you reached maximum amount of concurrent  sessions.

Comment: My system is running `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`. I've added a snippet from my auth.log.  It looks like the sessions are closed properly. `netstat -tupn` only shows my own active ssh session, no other connection.

Comment: Sniff ssh session with tcpdump on client side. According the logs termination originated by client. If the dump will confirm that, debug the client.